# Trouble with Faker class in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, faker

I'm using Laravel 9. I have a Factory with next:

```
$image = $this->faker->image('public/storage/posts', 640, 480, null, false);
```

The destination directory exists, is reachable, and has the appropiate permisions.
When I try to run the seeder, in the destination directory the file images appear and are immediately destroyed, so the directory remains empty when the seeder finishes.

How can I solve this problem with the Faker class?

Comment: Can you please try without the 4th and 5th parameter? and share your observation.

Comment: I tried without those parameters. It didn work all the same.

Comment: @Laura1995 did get the solution?